# How to use 16 bit floating point (half) data in both .C and .CU files?

Tags: cuda, floating-point

I am working on the project including both .C and .CU files. I want to use "half" data in the calculation and the data is operated in both .C and .CU file. But I found that "half" is only avaiable in .CU file and "__fp16" is in .C file on aarch64. I knew there is some library that defines half data type alone. However is there any better solution to solve this issue to make "half" visiable in both .C and .CU? Or any method to make "__fp16" visiable in .CU file that is also fine?
Thanks so much for help!!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735292/can-anyone-provide-sample-code-demonstrating-the-use-of-16-bit-floating-point-in) may be of interest.