# CUDA, cuBLAS and half precision data types

Tags: cuda, floating-point

Since CUDA 7.5/8.0 and devices with Pascal GPUs CUDA supports the half precision (FP16) datatype out of the box. Additionally, many of the BLAS calls inside CUBLAS support the half precision types, e.g. the GEMM operation available as `cublasHgemm`. My problem is that the host does not support half precision types. Is the an already implemented solution like `cublasSetMatrix` which does the conversion during the upload to the device? Or is it necessary to create a tricky implementation by composition a float upload with a CUDA kernel doing the truncation to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function currently provided by the CUDA toolkit which converts `float` quantities to `half` quantities in the process of copying data from host to device.

It is possible to convert from `float` to `half` either in host code or device code.  There would be advantages and disadvantages of doing it in either place.

Furthermore, there is a [`cublas<t>gemmEx`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-gemmEx) function available that may be of interest, which can have differing datatypes for input and output (and computation).

Some other `half` resources that may be of interest:

- [half conversion library](http://half.sourceforge.net/) by Christian Rau mentioned by @talonmies below
- CUDA [half intrinsics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__HALF.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__HALF).
- previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735292/can-anyone-provide-sample-code-demonstrating-the-use-of-16-bit-floating-point-in), with links to some other resources

Comment: Christian Rau has developed a very high quality host IEEE 754 half precision library today might be useful here