# CUDA compilation error: __hmul and __hneg are undefined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cuda

I'm trying to get half-precision intrinsics working on CUDA. The `half` type, and `__float2half()` and `__half2float()` functions compile and work as expected. However, I'm getting a compilation error whenever I reference `__hmul`, `__hneg` or similar. The exact error is:

```
identifier "__hmul" is undefined
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

__global__ void foo(float in, float multiplier, float& out)
{
    half in_half = __float2half(in);
    half multiplier_half = __float2half(multiplier);
    half out_half =  __hmul(in_half, multiplier_half);

    out = __half2float(out_half);
}
```

I've included what I believe are the right headers. Am I missing a header, or something else?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, compiling against `cudart_static.lib`, and targeting `sm_52` and `sm_61` (GTX 970 and above).

Comment: what compilation command are you using to compile this?

Comment: almost certainly this ^^ is the issue.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735292/can-anyone-provide-sample-code-demonstrating-the-use-of-16-bit-floating-point-in/32790812#32790812) may be of interest

Comment: what's your compilation command are you using to compile this ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CUDA compute capability versions `sm_52` and below do not support the `__hmul` function. The target needs to be at least `sm_53`.

In Visual Studio, go to your project properties, open the `Cuda C/C++` group and select the `Device` tab, then update the `Code Generation` settings so that all target architectures are `sm_53` or later.

Comment: Please remember to come back an accept this answer so that the question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag.

Comment: Done, thanks! Sorry – I was originally going to delete the question since the answer was trivial, but decided to self-answer and keep it up in the end. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with your earlier comments, talonmies and @RobertCrovella.